# Normalization/standardization of time series data

Tags: time-series, outliers, normalization, standardization

I have energy consumption data where rows represent different users and columns are different measurements. I don't really understand, how and in which order i need to normalize and standardize the data. First of all, there are different scaled users that I don't consider as outliers. The columns are also far from normally distributed. I want to "remove" the scale of different users and only look at the patterns so it would make sense to me to normalize the rows to have average of one (for example). But same time, normalization is said to be very sensitive to outliers. When applying outlier detection methods, i think it would be good if the columns were normally distributed and also the scaled should be normalized so that the outlier detection method doesn't only pick the big users.

So in what order should I execute this process? I would think Normalize rows->standardize columns->IQR or equivalent outlier detection method